# Continuous Deployment of a Node.js app to Heroku using GitLab

Tags: node.js, heroku, gitlab, gitlab-ci

There are tutorials covering the deployment of Ruby and Python apps but I can't find good documentation or examples for NodeJS.

http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/examples/test-and-deploy-python-application-to-heroku.html

http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/examples/test-and-deploy-ruby-application-to-heroku.html

Does anyone have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` to share?

Comment: This is a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452878/continuous-deployment-of-a-nodejs-using-gitlab

Answer (score 4):

1. create a project

```
 npm init -y
 npm i  #install dependencies
```

2. add the following lines in package.json

```
    "engines": {
        "node": "8.12.0",  //node version
        "npm": "6.4.1"     //npm version
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js", //heroku will using the following script to run node app
    }
```

3. create a heroku project

   1. select *NEW* -> *Create new app*
   2. set the *App name* & *choose a region*
   3. click on *Create app*
4. Gitlab setup create new repo or add to exist project given on gitlab website
5. create a .gitlab-ci.yml file

   ```
   image: node:latest
   stages:
   - production
   production:
   type: deploy
   stage: production
   image: ruby:latest
   script:
       - apt-get update -qy
       - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
       - gem install dpl
       - dpl --provider=heroku --app=APPNAME_OF_Heroku App --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY # security add the heroku api to CI/CD setting
   only:
       - master  #branch name to deploy on heroku
   ```
6. Setting *HEROKU_API_KEY*

   1. Setting -> CI/CD -> Variable -> Expand
   2. Input Variable key -> variable name in .gitlab-ci.yml
   3. Input Variable value -> Heroku Api Key
7. Get the Heroku Api Key

   4. Heroki Dashborad -> Account Settings
8. set the Runner on Gitlab

   1. Setting -> CI/CD -> Variable -> Expand

      1. Specific Runners

         1. Install the gitlab-runner
         2. [Windows](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html)
         3. [Linux](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html)
         4. [MacOS](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/osx.html)
         5. For setup steps [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html)
      2. Shared Runners

         1. just click *Disable shared Runners* to enable the shared runner
9. push the files to gitlab it will automatically deploy on heroku

   ```sh
   git add .                 #to add all the files)
   git commit -m "message"   #to commit files
   git push origin master
   ```

Comment: Why is the ruby image used?

Comment: you can refer to this [link](https://blog.heroku.com/docker-images-with-buildpacks)

Comment: we recently ran into some weird webpack build bugs and narrowed it down to the ruby image. Switching to the Node image (which makes more sense) fixed them.

Comment: We only used NodeJS for REST API, didn't involve any configurations so we didn;t ran in such issues .but good to know.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a detailed article for continuous integration on Heroku:

https://medium.com/@seulkiro/deploy-node-js-app-with-gitlab-ci-cd-214d12bfeeb5

**Sample .gitlab-ci.yml file :**

https://gitlab.com/seulkiro/node-heroku-dpl