# Continuous Deployment of a NodeJS using GitLab Ask Question

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I have an API developed in NodeJS and have successfully set up continuous integration via a `.gitlab-ci.yml file`. The next stage is to set up continuous deployment to Heroku.

There are plenty of tutorials covering the deployment of Ruby and Python apps but nothing on NodeJS. Currently my .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this:

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - production

production:
  type: deploy
  stage: production
  image: ruby:latest
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=app-heroku --api-key=key
  only:
    - master
```

I have two repositories on the `heroku`, the first for `development`, the second for `production`. First, I upload `gitlab` `development` to a branch, and this is deployed on `heroku` in the `development` repository. And if I upload a `gitlab` wizard to a branch, then on `heroku` it is deployed in a repository for `production`. How can this be implemented?

Comment: Continuous Deployment of a Node.js app to Heroku using GitLab
[refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55958980/9689561)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer following Question *Continuous Deployment of a Node.js app to Heroku using GitLab* [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55958980/9689561)